# Executa função x minutos após submeter formulário

Tags: php

Boa tarde galera do bem, apareceu um problema para resolver em um site, algo que ainda não havia mexido.

É o seguinte, na página tenho um formulário onde a pessoa pode se cadastrar. Ao realizar o cadastro, eu envio um email para ela confirmando esse cadastro.

Agora, vamos começar a utilizar SMS também, ou seja, a pessoa se cadastra, recebe um e-mail e um SMS confirmando (regras da empresa). Mas meu gestor quer que o SMS chegue depois de uns 5 min que a pessoa realizou o cadastro no site.

No momento, estou enviando o SMS de imediato, mas ele quer que seja feito da maneira como ele falou.

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Obs.: Eu submeto o formulário na mesma página que faço o insert.

```
function sendSms(){

            $nome = explode(" ",$_POST['txtNome']); // pega o nome via post , e joga cada palavra em um array

            $corrigir = array(' ','-','(',')','{','}','/','  ');// array que elimina caractres do telefone ,deixando somente os numeros 

            $corpoSMS = 'SKY HDTV:Caro(a).'$nome[0].',informamos que seus dados foram enviados para nosso dpt de cadastros.Dentro de 24h,entraremos em contato com maiores informacoes'; //monta o corpo do sms , mantendo o limite de 160 caracteres.

            $tel = str_replace($corrir,'',$_POST['txtCel']);

            $msg = str_replace(' ','+',$corpoSMS);

            //código da página enviapost.php
                $dados_post = array(
                        "" => $tel,
                        "?message=" => $msg,
                        );

                $context = stream_context_create(array(
                    'http' => array(
                    'method' => 'GET',
                    'header' => array(
                    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
                    'content' => http_build_query($dados_post)
                    )
                )
            );

        $host = 'https://meuservidordesms.com.br/'.$tel.'?message='.$msg;
            $result = file_get_contents($host,false,$context);

            if(preg_match("/SUCESSO/", $result)){
                    echo '  <script type="text/javascript">
                                alert("SMS enviado com sucesso!");
                            </script>';
                        } else {
                            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Erro enviar o SMS.<br>");</script>';
                    }

        }// FUNCAO QUE ENVIA O SMS AO CLIENTE.
```

Comment: Você já testou o impacto que teria deixar esses envios de SMS empilhados? Não gera gargalo no sistema? Teria algum problema se você salvasse isso em arquivo ou banco e depois rodasse uma tarefa a cada x tempos que lê-se esses dados e enviasse o mesmo. Exemplo de uma tarefa agendada? A grosso modo como se usasse um observer?

Comment: Boa noite, voce teria algum exemplo ou link mostrando como poderia fazer ? Grato

Comment: Uma thread que consulta no banco de dados a cada 5 segundos quais são os próximos SMS para enviar, nunca utilizei Thread no PHP, porém em outras linguagens como Delphi e Java. Segue uma documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.thread.php.

Comment: Talvez isso te ajude http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9047-PHP-Execute-asynchronous-tasks-in-the-background.html

Comment: Você pode utilizar um serviço de filas como: Amazon SQS, Beanstalkd, IronMQ, ...

Answer (score 2):

Como o Israel falou, talvez seja melhor você ter um serviço rodando no servidor, verificando os registros novos no banco de dados e mandando o SMS na hora programada.

De qualquer maneira, fiquei interessado na sua pergunta e pesquisei um pouco.
Parece que é possível contatar um **"*script* filho"** a partir do *script* que é acessado pelo cliente, usando *socket*. Esse *script* responde rapidamente ao **"*script* pai"** que em seguida desconecta - a partir daí, o **"*script* filho"** continua seu trabalho, em *background*.

**Aqui vai o "*script* pai":**

```
<?php

echo "Teste de Socket para Script Filho";

// Data para diferenciar o momento do acesso ao da criação do arquivo .txt
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$current_date = date('d/m/Y == H:i:s');

// Criando a conexao socket
$socketParaFilho = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80);

// Criando pacote HTTP
$paraScriptFilho = "POST /script.php?&param=value HTTP/1.0\n";
$paraScriptFilho .= "Host: www.example.com\n";

// A mensagem que sera enviada ao script filho
$dados = "Script Pai: pagina acessada em " . $current_date;
$paraScriptFilho .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($dados)."\n\n";

// Incluindo mensagem com a data em que a pagina foi visitada
$paraScriptFilho .= $dados;

// enviando pacote
fwrite($socketParaFilho, $paraScriptFilho);

// Esperando resposta do script "filho"
$resposta = fread($socketParaFilho, $dataSize);

// Fechando conexao
fclose($socketParaFilho);

?>
```

**Agora o "*script* filho", note que ele deve se chamar apenas "script.php":**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Aqui que acontece a "mágica"
ob_start();
ignore_user_abort(1);
set_time_limit(0);

$resposta = "OK";
echo $resposta;

ob_flush();

// A partir deste ponto, o "script pai" desconecta, e o script filho
// se mantêm em execução

sleep(60);
$arquivo = 'teste.txt';
$data = date('d/m/Y == H:i:s');
$texto = $post . "\r\nScript Filho: texto salvo em " . $data;
file_put_contents($arquivo, $texto);

?>
```

Depois de acessado o **"*script* pai"**, é possível até fechar a janela do navegador.
60 segundos depois, um documento .txt será criado no servidor, mostrando a data que a página foi acessada e a data que o **"*script* filho"** salvou o documento.

**Aqui está o resultado do meu teste:**

```
Script Pai: pagina acessada em 20/07/2015 == 05:00:03
Script Filho: texto salvo em 20/07/2015 == 05:01:03
```

Eu achei esse exemplo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833013/continue-php-execution-after-sending-http-response).

*PS. Eu não entendo de PHP. Vi esse exemplo e achei que poderia ajudar com a sua questão.*

Comment: Bom dia @Daniel , cara , tinha me esquecido dos sockets . Vou tentar aplicar ao meu caso , pois eu só estou fazendo a pagina de controle de cadastros ,o site foi uma agencia quem desenvolveu. Mas acredito que os sockets , vão suprir minhas necessidades. Obrigado